# data is saving perfectly in shared preferences but when i reopen data didn't remains in Shared Pref

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

here is the method for saving data, (i am trying to store list)

```
public void  saveListToPref() {
    editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonText = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString("list", jsonText);
    editor.commit();
    Log.v("save",""+editor.commit());
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Example data or example of usage of the method would be helpful. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26807806).

Comment: I am saving and retrieving data (String only) from QR code. and saving it into shared preferences.